Play/pause events not received after starting and stopping microphone recording
Audio service play/pause events work as expected at the beginning, but once I start (and later stop) recording using recorder library, the play/pause events are not received anymore. And that's even after I dispose of the recorder (call _audioRecorder.dispose()).
Here is a reproducible example (hit the microphone button to start recording, and then hit it again to stop recording): https://github.com/bartolomej/audio-service-headset-controls-example
Does anyone know the reason behind this or a possible workaround?
